# Java HashMap key not found?

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, byte

Why return false?

```
private static final HashMap<Integer, Integer> tags_tbl = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put(0x01, 1);
    put(0x8a, 1);
}};
```

tags_tbl.containsKey(-118) - this return false, why?
tags_tbl.containsKey(1) - this return true
tags_tbl.containsKey(0x8a) - this return true

0x8a = -118 in dec

Comment: Is `0x8a` interpreted as an unsigned `byte` or an unsigned `int`?

Comment: 0x8a is a byte, buffer[i]

Comment: It definitely is not. If it was a `byte`, your code wouldn't compile. It is an `int` (boxed to an `Integer`).

Comment: `0x8a = -118 in dec` can you explain why you think so?

Answer (score 0):

0x8a is an `int` literal, decimal value 138. If you want it treated as a `byte`, and sign extended during conversion to `int`, cast it first:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] main) {
    System.out.println(new Integer(0x8a));
    System.out.println(new Integer((byte)0x8a));
  }
}
```

prints:

```
138
-118
```

Comment: thx. How i can initialise HashMap as byte? HashMap<Byte, Integer> ?

Comment: If you intend the key to be Byte, declare it that way. If you prefer an Integer key, see the edited version of my program. There is an implicit boxing conversion to Integer if you use (byte)0x8a as a key for a HashMap<Integer,Integer>.